# Creating a platform that houses 2 existing platforms

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, monorepo

I have 2 existing projects that are independent of each other, and I was tasked to bring them together under a suite of some sort and share some small data between them. The problem is one platform is using ReactJs and the other using VueJs.

**Example:**
To give you a small example, it's like having Facebook and Instagram using different JS frameworks, and bringing them together under one platform `let's call it Meta` so the user goes to one platform and finds all products that the company offers.

(Example of the data that needs to be shared: Dark/Light Mode, User is logged, ....)

And is it possible to wrap both apps inside another, like having a whole new project consisting of a Navbar and a body, and the body switches between showing the first and the second platform using the navbar links?

Please if you have any suggestions throw them at me.

Comment: Ultimately both apps will produce JavaScript which you can import onto a page. Provided you're deploying both applications under one domain, you could use something like Local Storage or a Cookie to store your user preferences, or a token even that would indicate if the user is logged and who they are.

Comment: I had an idea that I don't know if it's feasible, let's say I want to wrap both apps inside another app. 
Following the example, I gave, having a new app **Meta** which is simply a landing page with a navbar with a list of links **/Facebook** and **/Instagram** but still having **Meta**'s Navbar.

I don't know if I got the idea across that well, but in general, I want to wrap a whole app inside another, if there a possibility for that?